# What is the difference between SQL, PL-SQL and T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql

What is the difference between SQL, PL-SQL and T-SQL?

Can anyone explain what the differences between these three are, and provide scenarios where each would be relevantly used?

Comment: The query language that Microsoft SQL Server uses is a variant of the ANSI-standard
Structured Query Language, SQL. The SQL Server variant is called Transact-SQL.

Comment: SQL is a data oriented language for selecting and manipulating sets of data. PL/SQL is a procedural language to create applications

Comment: SQL is structured query language PL/SQL is a procedural language extended to sql it is developed by oracle T-SQL is developed by microsoft

Answer (score 414, accepted):

SQL is a declarative language to operate on relational data: tables, views, resultsets and similar.

It's more or less standardized, and used by almost all relational database management systems: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, DB2, Informix, etc.

Most database engines also support procedural languages (as opposed to declarative that SQL is). They have variables, loops, conditional operators and explicitly controlled execution flow, something that SQL lacks. Usually they are designed to closely integrate with SQL.

They are, for the most part, used to write stored procedures: pieces of code that live on the server and implement complex business rules that are hard or impossible to implement with pure set-based operations.

- PL/SQL is a proprietary procedural language used by Oracle
- PL/pgSQL is a procedural language used by PostgreSQL
- TSQL is a proprietary procedural language used by Microsoft in SQL Server.

Comment: TSQL is also used by Sybase; at least in Oracle, PL/SQL procedures can do a lot more than just manage "business rules"; PL/SQL procedures can access web sites, send email etc.

Comment: PL/SQL doesn't solely exist in the database, e.g. Oracle Forms contains a client-side implementation of PL/SQL.

Comment: Note each database has it's own implementation of SQL (T-SQL and PL/SQL being two of the more common), ANSII standard SQL is often used when multiple backends are used, but not all databases use all ANSII SQL features either. And the database specific implementation of SQl tends to be the one that performs best for that database - after all they have to give you a reason to use their database, right?

Comment: Correction: SQL is a language to operate on tables for which SQL itself provides the definition. The SQL Standard avoids the words 'set' and 'relation' and their derivatives. SQL tables are not sets.

Comment: It sure would be nice to have a sql procedural language that would work across oracle and sql server.

Comment: Another procedural language is DB2's SQL-PL that conforms to the standard SQL/PSM

Comment: There's an app that converts PL/SQL to T-SQL. Still have to manually code review and make sure it worked though.

Comment: I think that PL/pgSQL is the same as PL/SQL and offered same capabilities, at least it was like ten years ago (2010)

Comment: A common misunderstanding is that PL/SQL is the name for Oracle's dialect of SQL, which it absolutely is not. In Oracle there is a very clear distinction between the in-database compiled programming language (PL/SQL) and the query language (SQL).

Answer (score 124):

**SQL**

> SQL is used to communicate with a database, it is the standard
>   language for relational database management systems.

In detail **Structured Query Language** is a special-purpose programming language designed for managing data held in a relational database management system (RDBMS), or for stream processing in a relational data stream management system (RDSMS).

Originally based upon relational algebra and tuple relational calculus, SQL consists of a data definition language and a data manipulation language. The scope of SQL includes data insert, query, update and delete, schema creation and modification, and data access control. Although SQL is often described as, and to a great extent is, a declarative language (4GL), it also includes procedural elements.

**PL/SQL**

***PL/SQL is a combination of SQL along with the procedural features of programming languages.*** It was developed by Oracle Corporation

> Specialities of PL/SQL

- completely portable, high-performance transaction-processing
  language.
- provides a built-in interpreted and OS independent programming
  environment.
- directly be called from the command-line SQL*Plus interface.
- Direct call can also be made from external programming language calls
  to database.
- general syntax is based on that of ADA and Pascal programming
  language.
- Apart from Oracle, it is available in TimesTen in-memory database and
  IBM DB2.

**T-SQL**

**Short for Transaction-SQL**, an extended form of SQL that adds declared variables, transaction control, error and exceptionhandling and row processing to SQL

The Structured Query Language or SQL is a programming language that focuses on managing relational databases. **SQL has its own limitations** which spurred the software giant **Microsoft to build on top of SQL with their own extensions to enhance the functionality of SQL**.
Microsoft added code to SQL and called it Transact-SQL or T-SQL. Keep in mind that T-SQL is proprietary and is under the control of Microsoft while SQL, although developed by IBM, is already an open format.

**T-SQL adds a number of features that are not available in SQL.**

This includes procedural programming elements and a local variable to provide more flexible control of how the application flows. A number of functions were also added to T-SQL to make it more powerful; functions for mathematical operations, string operations, date and time processing, and the like. These additions make T-SQL comply with the Turing completeness test, a test that determines the universality of a computing language. SQL is not Turing complete and is very limited in the scope of what it can do.

Another significant difference between T-SQL and SQL is the changes done to the DELETE and UPDATE commands that are already available in SQL. With T-SQL, the DELETE and UPDATE commands both allow the inclusion of a FROM clause which allows the use of JOINs. This simplifies the filtering of records to easily pick out the entries that match a certain criteria unlike with SQL where it can be a bit more complicated.

**Choosing between T-SQL and SQL is all up to the user.** Still, using T-SQL is still better when you are dealing with Microsoft SQL Server installations. This is because T-SQL is also from Microsoft, and using the two together maximizes compatibility. SQL is preferred by people who have multiple backends.

**References** 
, Wikipedea
, Tutorial Points 
:www.differencebetween.com

Comment: IMO that is currently the best answer (however, manoj's answer and blog post are worth a read too).

Comment: Wasn't T-SQL bought from Sybase along with the database code they bought to make the first SQL server version ? At least T-SQL also works on Sybase so I'd think there is some 'common code'

Comment: Actually, Microsoft and Sybase jointly developed SQL Server for OS2. So, both companies worked jointly on developing T-SQL.  That is why both databases can use T-SQL although there are significant differences between the two variants of T-SQL.

Comment: Calling PL/SQL *"a combination of SQL along with the procedural features of programming languages"* might give the impression that it is an extended dialect of SQL, when in fact it is an in-database compiled programming language that embeds SQL natively. A routine irritation on technical forums is when people say they have a PL/SQL question when in fact they have an Oracle SQL question.

Answer (score 45):

- `SQL` a language for talking to the
  database. It lets you select data,
  mutate and create database objects
  (like tables, views, etc.), change
  database settings.
- `PL-SQL` a procedural programming language (with embedded SQL)
- `T-SQL`
  (procedural) extensions for SQL used
  by SQL Server

Comment: Should be SPL (Stored Procedure Lang), PL is too general (ie, C).

Answer (score 34):

**1. SQL** or Structured Query Language was developed by IBM for their product "System R".

Later **ANSI** made it as a **Standard** on which all Query Languages are based upon and have extended this to create their own DataBase Query Language suits. The first standard was **SQL-86** and latest being **SQL:2016**

**2. T-SQL** or Transact-SQL was developed by **Sybase** and later co-owned by **Microsoft** SQL Server.

**3. PL/SQL** or Procedural Language/SQL was **Oracle** Database, known as "Relation Software" that time.

I've documented this in my [blog post](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/05/03/what-is-sql-plsql-t-sql-and-difference-between-them/).

Comment: This answer is more thorough than the approved answer, and the blog post is a great read.

Answer (score 6):

Structured Query Language - SQL: is an ANSI-standard used by almost all SGBD's vendors around the world. Basically, SQL is a language used to define and manipulate data [DDL and DML].

PL/SQL is a language created by Oracle universe. PL/SQL combine programming procedural instructions and allows the creation of programs that operates directly on database scenario.

T-SQL is Microsoft product align SQL patterns, with some peculiarities. So, feel free to test your limits.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a standard and there are many database vendors like Microsoft,Oracle who implements this standard using their own proprietary language.

Microsoft uses T-SQL to implement SQL standard to interact with data whereas oracle uses PL/SQL.