# Is Oracle's database language SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

The question sounds a bit weird, but basically, SQL is different from MySQL and I think Microsoft SQL too (not too sure). What about Oracle? The wiki page for SQL didn't mention if Oracle is a variant, and I can't find anything on Oracle's website. The answer may be there, but the site is hard to navigate.

My boss asked me to read up on SQL. The project is using Oracle database. Does studying vanilla SQL count or is Oracle's database language different?

Comment: SQL dialect like in real world + PL/SQL procedural part which is Oracle specific. So first learn Oracle SQL(but be aware that it may introduce things that are not in standard SQL) then procedural language.

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL is the standard, some products' SQL are closer to the standard, and some are not very close at all...

Comment: There is no 100% ANSI SQL database server (except experimental). Every real DB has its dialect: PL/SQL, T-SQL, etc.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between SQL, PL-SQL and T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043265/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-pl-sql-and-t-sql)

Comment: So to learn the SQL used on Oracle, what should I be looking for?

Comment: You could [start with the Oracle documentation overview](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/sqllangu.htm). Beyond that it depends what you will be doing, what your company will pay for (books, courses), what local expertise or on-the-job training is available, etc.

Comment: There is an ANSI standard for SQL.  Oracle complies with that standard, as do most relational database engines.  Where differences occur between database engines are in functions.  For example, many database engines have dateadd and datediff functions.  Oracle does not.  If you are brand new to sql, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.  Remember, the S is SQL stands for Structured, not Standard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I learned that there is an "SQL standard", as ***jarlh*** told, ANSI/ISO SQL, and every database manager (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc) has its own syntax for different cases and internal working, near this standard, like use the commit command or not, datatypes, etc.

For example:

[comparison page on SQL](http://www.bristle.com/Tips/SQL.htm#Differences%20in%20Built-In%20Functions)